# rsnapshot produces a double backup of localhost/media

Tags: incremental-backup, rsnapshot

I use rsnapshot in my Xen host to backup all vms via their snapshots.

Now rsnapshot backups everything double, because it creates an extra "localhost" folder in each daily backup, that contains everything in /media/snapshots again.

for example those are the same files:

```
/backup-sda4/rsnapshot/.sync/localhost/media/snapshots/tmp-vm01.myserver.de-var/backups/mysql
```

and

```
/backup-sda4/rsnapshot/.sync/vm01/media/snapshots/tmp-vm01.myserver.de-var/backups/mysql
```

This is my config:

```
config_version  1.2
snapshot_root   /backup-sda4/rsnapshot/
no_create_root  1
cmd_cp      /bin/cp
cmd_rm      /bin/rm
cmd_rsync   /usr/bin/rsync
cmd_logger  /usr/bin/logger

retain      daily   7
retain      weekly  4
retain  monthly 3

verbose     2

loglevel    2

logfile /var/log/rsnapshot.log

lockfile    /var/run/rsnapshot.pid

rsync_long_args     --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --stats

sync_first  1

backup  /root/      dom0/
backup  /etc/       dom0/

backup  /media/snapshots/tmp-vm01.mysqrver.de-var/www/    vm01/
backup  /media/snapshots/tmp-vm01.mysqrver.de-var/backups/mysql/  vm01/
```

There is no mention of `localhost` in the config.

How do I prevent the extra localhost backup? is this default somehow?

This ist my /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot

```
30 4    * * *           root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot sync && /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
0  4    * * 1           root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
30 3    1 * *           root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly
```

Comment: The `.sync` directory suggests to me that you're actually looking inside some sort of snapshot folder. If not, where did that component of the paths come from?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the files in `.sync/localhost` were created previously in an early stage of the server and are not being deleted by

```
rsnapshot sync
```

in the cron job. It seems like `rsnapshot sync` only syncs existing defined backup directories in rsnapshot.conf, but **does not delete folders, that are not defined** there. To me this seems a bit buggy, I posted it also here:

https://github.com/rsnapshot/rsnapshot/issues/220#issuecomment-446615967